# Any way to password-protect a Site.com site?

Tags: site.com

Just need to forbid access to a site.com site to all but one source. Some way to use htaccess or other server side access control would be perfect. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not support .htaccess files.  You can set [IP restrictions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_ip_overview.htm&language=en_US) to only allow access to certain IP addresses and forbid all others access. Obviously, that wouldn't work for you if you couldn't narrow down your one source to be a single IP address or range.

The [Adding IP Restrictions help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_ip_set.htm&language=en_US) has the detailed step by step process, but basically you just hover over the page, template, or asset in the site content or page listing, click the little settings gear and select Add IP Restrictions and then fill out the information. For example:
[image: IP Restrictions for Site.com]

Comment: Very cool idea. This could handle doing what we need. Thanks as always for your expertise on this. I'm actually surprised I forgot about this built-in functionality.

Comment: Great! I've never actually used it, but it seems like a nice feature to limit something to internal users easily.